# using data one by one of two different variable to replace words using sed

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have two files say list1.txt and list2.txt

- list1.txt have some name say A B C D
- list2.txt have some names say 1 2 3 4

I have stored those two lists data in two variables say

```
var1=$(<list1.txt)
var2=$(<list2.txt)
```

I have another file that contain X Y names in that
Now i want to make files by replacing those two X Y with one data from list1 and one with list2
Say i have to create 4 files
file1 will have A 1 file2 will have B 2 and so on...

Please help me out as i have to make several files with the data stored in those two list files.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to use `paste` to join corresponding lines of `list1.txt` and `list2.txt` and then use `split` to split the result into multiple output files, with one line per file.

```
split -a 1 -d -l 1 <(paste -d" " list1.txt  list2.txt) out
```

The other way is to use arrays:

```
arr1=( $(<list1.txt) )
arr2=( $(<list2.txt) )

for (( i=0; i<${#arr1[@]}; i++ ))
do
     echo "${arr1[$i]} ${arr2[$i]}" > "out$i"
done
```